# Firebase fails to authenticate no matter what

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K5Ba.png)I'm trying to use firebase authentication and I made it show me 'authentication failed' in the catch case and 'success' otherwise, but it only shows me the 'authentication failed' message even when I type in completely new email and password.

```
  //the firebase code
  this.state={
        email: '',
        password: '',
        errorMessage: '',
    }
    const {email, password} = this.state;
    this.setState({errorMessage: 'success'});
    this.onButtonPress = () =>{
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .catch(() => {
            firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, 
    password)
            .catch(() => {
                this.setState({errorMessage: 'Failed to Authenticate'});
            });
        });
    }

    //I'm grabbing the email and password from the textInput and 
    assigning them to this.state.email and this.state.password

           <InputField
                fieldText={'Email:'}
                onChangeText={email => this.setState({email})}
                value={this.state.email}
                placeholder={'Please enter your email'} />

     // and the password is the same except for this.state.password and 
     setState

     //the component:
     <Text style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'red', alignSelf: 'center'}}> 
     {this.state.errorMessage}</Text>
        <Inline>
            <Button buttonText={'Log In'}
            onPress={this.onButtonPress}
            />
```

Comment: try logging the error you get from the catch clause and edit the question with the error

Answer (score 0):

You have .catch and .catch on firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)

maybe that's the problem ? it should be .then for success and .catch for error

if you want print real problem simply do it like this

```js
            .catch((e) => {
              console.log(e)
            });
```